# Why is the onTap function using the wrong item in the for loop flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

```
if (eventsList != null && eventsList.events != null) {
      for (var event in eventsList.events) {
        var currentEvent = event; // Create a local copy of the event
        markers.add(
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId("${id}"), // Assuming event has an id property
            position: LatLng(currentEvent.latitude, currentEvent.longitude),
            
            onTap: () {
              // Inside the onTap callback, use the local copy of the event
              print(currentEvent.title);
              print(currentEvent.longitude);
              print(currentEvent.latitude);
              _onEventMarkerTap(currentEvent);
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }`
```

I am trying to create a marker on google maps for all of the events in this event list. The event is displayed at the correct location meaning that currentEvent.latitude and currentEvent.longitude work above the onTap function, but inside of the onTap function it defaults to the same event every time instead of the current event in the list. Wondering why this is happening, thank you inn advance

I was expecting the ontap for the marker to use the event the marker was created with.

Comment: use `event` not `currentEvent`.  that will become a closure variable, unique to every callback.  Instead, you're building multiple callbacks that all point to the final value of that shared variable.